# Swapping a CSS class on jQuery .load event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list styled with CSS - standard stuff.  The items within that feature jQuery .load to load the relevant info into another div.  This works fine, however I also need to change the class in the list to reflect which item has been loaded.  My existing code below, which will probably explain it better...

```
<ul class="inner-nav" id="tdlists">
  <li class="active"><a onclick="$('##showlist').load('/lists/?List=#ListID#');">#ListName#</a></li>
  <li><a onclick="$('##showlist').load('/lists/?List=#ListID#');">#ListName#</a></li>
  <li><a onclick="$('##showlist').load('/lists/?List=#ListID#');">#ListName</a></li>
</ul>
```

The actual list is populated by a db query, however I've stripped that out as I don't believe it's relevant to the question and would only complicate matters!

Comment: for some reason, my code has been truncated in my example, but suffice to say it ends with </li></ul>

Comment: Why are you using 2 `#` in your ID selectors?

Comment: @undefined - I'm using Coldfusion, the double hash is required to escape it.  Sorry, I should probably have edited that bit out too.  The front-end sees it as a single hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `this` context set by jQuery for the load callback. For example:

```
$('#showlist').load('/lists/?List=#ListID#', function(){ 
    $(this).addClass('loaded') 
});
```

As a additional tip, is better if you use event delegation instead of writing the onclick attribute for each li tag:

```
$('#tdlists').on('click', 'li a', function () {
    $('#showlist').load('/lists/?List=#ListID#', function(){ 
           $(this).addClass('loaded') 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.load()` event should have an event handler that will fire when the event is triggered, so you could set your class in there.

```
$('#showlist').load('/lists/?List=#ListID#',
    function(){
        //Add class or perform your logic here
        $('#showlist').addClass(x););
    }
);
```

**[.Load() | jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)**

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.load can be passed a callback method which runs on completion.  This could then update the class on the parent.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```